# What's the difference between dim(data)[-1] and dim(data)[1]

Tags: r, dataframe

I read both dim(data)[-1] and dim(data)[1] in some code but I can't figure out the difference. Don't they both address the column dimension of a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` is a dataframe. `dim(data)[-1]` would return number of columns whereas `dim(data)[1]` would return number of rows.

As an example using `mtcars` dataset -

```
dim(mtcars)[-1]
#[1] 11

dim(mtcars)[1]
#[1] 32
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But why not use 0 and 1 to address rows/columns instead of -1 and 1?

Comment: R indexing starts at 1. So yes, you can use `dim(data)[1]` and `dim(data)[2]` and it would be the same.